I'm facing an issue in NextAuth where I want the cookies to be stored in my browser before redirecting after sign-in
Issue with Storing Cookies Before Redirect in NextAuth.js
I am using NextAuth.js in my Next.js project and I'm facing an issue where I want cookies (like accessToken) to be stored in the browser before redirecting after a successful sign-in. However, even after trying different libraries such as js-cookie and nookies, the cookies are still not being set.
Below is the relevant part of my code:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import FacebookProvider from 'next-auth/providers/facebook';
import Cookie from 'js-cookie';
import { setCookie } from "nookies";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization: {
                params: { scope: "profile email" }
            }
        }),
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    session: { jwt: true },
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('url', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        first_name: profile.given_name,
                        last_name: profile.family_name,
                        email: profile.email,
                        country_id: "13",
                        ip: '127.0.0.1',
                        platform: 'web',
                        provider: account.provider,
                        social_user_id: profile.sub,
                    }),
                });

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    user.accessToken = data.response.data.token;
                    user.profile = profile;
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error signing in', error);
                return false;
            }
        },
        async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
            if (user) {
                token.accessToken = account.accessToken;
                token.user = user;
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            session.user = token.user;

            Cookie.set('accessToken', token.accessToken, {
                expires: 7, // 7 days
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                sameSite: 'strict',
            });

            setCookie(null, 'accessToken', token.accessToken, {
                maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
                path: '/',
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                sameSite: 'strict',
            });

            return session;
        },
        async redirect() {
            return `/my-account`;
        },
    },
});

What I've Tried

I've tried using js-cookie and nookies to store the accessToken cookie, but it doesn't seem to be working before the redirect happens.
I want the cookies to be stored securely and be accessible across my Next.js app after sign-in.

Question
How can I make sure the cookies are properly stored before redirecting the user? Any help or guidance is appreciated!

If you're using Next.JS ver. 15, make the headers() function asynchronous. If not, don't.
Try to change your signIn callback to this code:
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                first_name: profile.given_name,
                last_name: profile.family_name,
                email: profile.email,
                country_id: "13",
                ip: '127.0.0.1',
                platform: 'web',
                provider: account.provider,
                social_user_id: profile.sub,
            }),
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
            const data = await response.json();

            (await cookies()).set("token", data.response.data.token); // new code
            // Be sure, there is a token data.response.data.token, because it looks like unusual, just test it by console.log() and see data on console

            user.accessToken = data.response.data.token;
            user.profile = profile;
            return true;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error signing in', error);
        return false;
    }
},


I am using Next.js 14.2, so I cannot import next/headers inside the pages directory.
Error:
× You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/ directory
